# Thoughts on the new superuser logo and theme?

Tags: discussion, style, logo

Based on the comments in [superuser.com Logo Vote](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/superuser-com-logo-vote/) and this [mock up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/want-to-browse-meta-with-the-upcoming-superuser-stylesheet-logo) I thought it worth canvassing opinions on the subject.

Answer (score 6):

I like the logo - in fact, seeing as it was chosen by a vote, I'm betting that the majority of initial users will as well. I would've picked a bit of a paler blue, but maybe my eyes are just a bit too used to the soothing greys of Meta.

Comment: i also think the logo looks great in my bookmark bar, it the best looking one actually... :-)

Answer (score 4):

Personally I think the logo is uninspiring and the blue and black is a bit... old-fashioned. The blue in the mock up (if accurate) is not attractive.

Answer (score 3):

The colors are peaceful and soothing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a big fan, I just about asked "why does the superuser logo suck?" on here.  I suppose a lot of people liked it though, so that wouldn't be nice. I like the colors.  I don't think that guy looks super, he looks pretty glum.

Answer (score 0):

I like it, somewhat. I find the colours pleasing to the eye, inviting, and friendly. However, the ['} seems a little too dotcom for me - like the logos of the long forgotten websites of the dotcom boom and bust era.

Out of the options available for voting, it is undoubtedly the best option, but I think there could be better. However, I'm no graphic designer or marketing guru, so I doubt I could improve on it much. Unlike Stack Overflow and Server Fault, I find it hard to conceptualize the name to an image for Super User - all that springs to mind is a needle and I think that's the wrong message.

I should add that I wasn't around to take part in the vote and therefore, probably am not worthy to comment, but [the logo with a cursor inside a star](http://img3.crowdspring.com/var/crowdspring/storage/images/projects/graphic_design/logo/logo_for_superuser_com/gallery/superuser__108/image_superuser/10636397-1-eng-US/image_superuser_gridview.jpg) seems a better image to go next to the current text.

Of course, it's important to give due reverence to the declarations made when the vote was announced where Jeff stated:

> I do not put a lot of stock in
> crowdsourcing design feedback (the
> poll winner may not “win”), but it
> will factor some in our final
> decision.

So, I doubt this thread matters much other than as a place to vent at our inability to effect a change.

Comment: http://www.bigeye.com/donotgo.htm

Answer (score 0):

I liked the colors and like the logo too much, just one thing i don't like about the logo that its not in the same way as his brothers "SO,SF"

Answer (score 0):

I like the colours and style of the site, but I don't like the logo.

Answer (score 0):

I voted for the logo and I still like it. Jeff made the decision process extremely visible on the blog. I find SuperUser exciting, having been on ServerFault and StackOverflow for a while.